# Extract the value of double quotation or String of string variable

Tags: java, string

I want to extract the value of double quotation or String of string variable for example. `""14.62647""`

I want to get the value `14.62647`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution1**

If the string can contain multiple results you can use this regex `\"\"(.*?)\"\"` with Pattern to get any thing between double quotation like this :

```
String str = "some string \"\"14.62647\"\" some string";
String regex = "\"\"(.*?)\"\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
14.62647
```

#### regex demo

---

**Solution2**

if the string contain only one result you can use [String::replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to replace every thing with the matched group between double quotation :

```
String str = "\"\"14.62647\"\"";
str = str.replaceAll("\"\"(.*?)\"\"", "$1");//output = 14.62647
```

Answer (score 1):

use a String#replace method:

```
    String myDoubleString = "\"\"14.62647\"\"";
    String result = myDoubleString.replace("\"\"", "");
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: This will remove the quotes, not extract the number. What if the input String is ``Foo ""14.62647"" Bar``?